# Using htaccess to remove ".html" at the end of my static files--but now, any URL with a trailing "/" causes an error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a static website with HTML files. I cobbled together the htaccess to implement the following:

1. domain.xyz/xxx.html -> domain.xyz/xxx
2. http -> https
3. [www.domain.xyz](http://www.domain.xyz) -> domain.xyz
4. Send all 404 errors to custom error.html page

Until today when I was setting up a 301-redirect from my old website. The filename/url of the old site's page and new site's page are exactly the same, but the problem was that the old site's URL had a trailing "/"... and when the URL on the new website is given a trailing "/", I get an error.

A 404 error, to be exact. My custom error page still appears (although it is wonky since it does not know how to deal with my relative soft-links).

How do I solve this?

Here is my htaccess:

```
#HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
#Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

#REMOVE EXT REDIRECT WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]

#404
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html
```

Comment: `when the URL on the new website is given a trailing "/", I get an error.` - What error are you getting?

Comment: In the old site, `https://oldsite/something/` worked but `https://newsite/something/` does not?  From your htaccess, `https://newsite/something/` will be rewritten as `https://newsite/something/.html`.  The extra `/` is the issue.  Change your RewriteRule to remove any `/` suffix.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500, how do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Match an optional slash at the end, but don't include it in the capture group. `^([^\.]+)/?$`